# Android Studio reference resources inside xml preference screen

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-preferences

I added xml resource file to xml directory as Preference Screen, when I am writing tag elements or attributes the code autocomplete is working fine.
The problem when I was trying reference to string resource like that `@string/pref_key_temp` the autocomplete didn't work, although if I wrote it by myself the editor gets the resource value as usual.

In other xml files the autocomplete is working fine, my problem just in preference screen file. I searched about that but I didn't find any related problems.

[image: preference screen autocomplete]

I have android studio 2.3 and I want to know if anyone has the same problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Same in Android Studio 3.0.1

Comment: Why not update to Android Studio 3.1?

Comment: @y.allam I'm teaching android development and my students have the same version so I won't make changes. Is it working with you on V 3.1?

Comment: @MohamedElSawaf yes, working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated the android studio to version 3.1.1 and the problem is solved.